# Use data attr value to get other data attr value

Tags: javascript

Situation as followed:

If have a bunch of images with data attributes: data-selected and data-id

```
<img src="" alt="" data-id="2" title="" class="selected" data-selected="1">
<img src="" alt="" data-id="4" title=""  data-selected="0">
<img src="" alt="" data-id="5" title="" class="selected" data-selected="1">
<img src="" alt="" data-id="7" title=""  data-selected="0">
```

I want to get all elements with data-selected="1"

Atm I tried this with:

```
var interests = document.querySelectorAll("[data-selected='1']");
```

Once the elements are gathered in a var I want to get all the data-id values of these elements.

So something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < interest.length; ++i){
        var id += interest[i].attr("data-id") . ";";
    }
```

Anyone who knows a better angle on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

--
Can't seem to find an answer in mentioned topic

[What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: Don't seem to find an answer to my problem in that topic @AndrewL.

Comment: How so? It's also a bit unclear what your question is

Comment: I'll rephrase @AndrewL.

Comment: Do `element.dataset.id`.

Comment: Q edited; if i do that with my code so far dataset.id = undefined
I need a different approach on this but don't know how @AndrewL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Array.apply(null, document.querySelectorAll("[data-selected='1']")).
  forEach(function (e) { console.log(e.getAttribute('data-id')); });
```

```html
<div data-selected='1' data-id="sel1"></div>
<div data-selected='1' data-id="sel2"></div>
<div data-selected='1' data-id="sel3"></div>
<div data-selected='1' data-id="sel4"></div>
<div data-selected='1' data-id="sel5"></div>
<div data-selected='1' data-id="sel6"></div>

<!-- should not get next -->
<div data-selected='2' data-id="sel7"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you, sir. From here I can continue